# access sqlite from another application

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

i'm using sqlite in my app and i created another app with configurations for my first app, only to update the sqlite options for my main app. But i can't access the same sqlite database.

If i use the configuration app and execute a update query, my database is updated but only in configuration app. For example the IP, i need to update the IP of my main app in the configuration.

I'm using this same class in my two apps.

```
public class BDCore extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "NewPointerBI";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 3;

    public BDCore(Context ctx){
        super(ctx, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("create table user(code integer primary key, ip text not null");


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("drop table user;");
        onCreate(db);

    }


}
```

and access with this same class:

```
public class DBLiteConnection {
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBLiteConnection(Context ctx){
        DBCore dbcore = new DBCore(ctx);
        db = dbcore.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public DBLiteUser search() {
        DBLiteUser user = new DBLiteUser();
        String[] columns = new String[]{"code", "ip"};
        Cursor cursor = db.query("user", columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            user.setCode(cursor.getInt(0));
            user.setIp(cursor.getString(1));
        }
        return user;
    }

    public void updateconfig(int code, String ip){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("ip",ip);
        db.update("user", values, "code = "+code, null);
    }

    public void insertdata(int code){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("code",1);
        values.put("ip","xxx.xxx.xxx");
        db.insert("user", null, values);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't access anoter app private folder. So either store the db on the storage or give your real app a content provider

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use a Content Provider to transfer the data between apps.